# Sending mail with PHP in forgein languages

Tags: html, php

I have a php mail script that works well except for one minor fact. In Outlook (all version), the email comes in gibrish. If the email is read through an internet browser (like Gmail.com), it's fine. Is it possible to have the email look good in Outlook as well? I tried emailing it as HTML, still to no avail.

I can post the full code if necessary, but it looks something like this:

these are the headers:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: Text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-8";
```

uses the mail() function:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I've tried to find ways to maybe encode incoming Outlook messages differently, but I (1) couldn't find a way to do so, and (2) would rather have it this way since it's supposed to go to a lot of people.

EDIT: After adding the line below, the message properly rendered both in browsers as well as Outlook. Hope this helps someone!

```
//convert to utf-8
$message = mb_convert_encoding( $message , 'ISO-8859-8' , 'utf-8' );
```

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: I suspect you are working with Hebrew, yes? It sounds like it's an issue with outlook, not PHP, especially since you confirmed that it works in browsers. Perhaps it has to do with Windows and/or Outlook.

Comment: @Moshe: Yes it is Hebrew, and it's definitely an Outlook rendering issue. Though I was able to solve it with PHP encoding, see EDIT for solution

Comment: Heh, good to see that you got it working. I noticed the encoding but I figured you knew what you were doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be pretty easy, change `charset=ISO-8859-8` to `charset=UTF-8`

Also be sure the creating page is encoded as `UTF-8` and that if a database is used, the table ( or whole db ) is in `UTF-8 unicode general`

With `UTF-8` you can write the characters as they appear, don't use entities.

Comment: I suspect this will work. It took me quite a while to find a solution, so I posted what worked for me under the EDIT section in the question. Thanks for your input