# Output displayed in email sent from forms doesn't show in Thai language

Tags: php, html, mysql

I really need help with getting my form to email the output in Thai language. I've been trying to fix it but I think that I don't have enough knowledge or understanding on this so it's time I seeked help.

I checked phpMyAdmin, the settings are like this..

```
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 
Server connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

My form is (briefly) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Tell A Friend</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="Tell A Friend" name="Tell A Friend" method="post" action="tellafriend.php">
<table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="250" align="right">ชื่อผู้เสนอเพื่อน :</td>
<td width="258"><label for="name"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield1">
  <label for="name2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">อีเมลล์ของผู้เสนอเพื่อน :</td>
<td><label for="email"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield2">
  <label for="email2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">เบอร์โทรศัพท์ของผู้เสนอเพื่อน :</td>
<td><label for="phone"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield3">
  <label for="phone2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">ชื่อเพื่อนที่ต้องการแนะนำ :</td>
<td><label for="friendsname"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield4">
  <label for="friendsname2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="friendsname" id="friendsname2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">อีเมลล์ของเพื่อนที่ต้องการแนะนำ :</td>
<td><label for="friendsemail"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield5">
  <label for="friendsemail2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="friendsemail" id="friendsemail2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">เบอร์โทรศัพท์ของเพื่อนที่ต้องการแนะนำ :</td>
<td><label for="friendsphone"></label>
  <span id="sprytextfield6">
  <label for="friendsphone2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="friendsphone" id="friendsphone2" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">กรุณากรอก</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$autoreply="Dear $name,\n\nThank you for visiting the Thai Au Pair website and for telling your friend about us!\n\nWe hope you and your friend do not let this great opportunity of being an Au pair 
abroad pass you by!\n\nThanks again and we look forward to welcoming you both to our office!\n\nThai Au Pair Team\n\nสวัสดีค่ะ\n\nขอบคุณที่ได้เยี่ยมชมเว็บไซด์ไทยออแพร์ของเรา และยังได้แนะนำเพื่อนๆ ที่อาจจะสนใจโครงการออแพร์ของเราอีกด้วยนะคะ\n\nทางทีมงานหวังเป็นอย่างยิ่งว่าคุณและเพื่อนจะได้มีโอกาสเป็นหนึ่งในสมาชิกของโครงการ ในขณะที่ยังสามารถเข้าร่วมได้อยู่ อย่าปล่อยให้เวลาผ่านไปนะคะ และขอขอบพระคุณอีกครั้งสำหรับความสนใจ โดยทีมงานหวังว่าจะได้มีโอกาสได้ต้อนรับคุณและเพื่อนที่ออฟฟิศไทยออแพร์ในเร็วๆ นี้นะคะ";
$subject="Thaiaupair.com-Thank you for your submission.";
mail($email, $subject, $autoreply);

$friendsname=$_POST['friendsname'];
$friendsemail=$_POST['friendsemail'];
$friendsphone=$_POST['friendsphone'];
$autoreply="Dear $friendsname,\n\nYour friend, $name, thinks you might be interested in the Au Pair program. Click on this link below to view our official website:\n\nhttp://www.thaiaupair.com\n\nWe look forward to welcoming both you and your friend to a new life experience abroad!\n\nThai Au Pair Team\n\nสวัสดีค่ะ\n\nเพื่อนของคุณชื่อ $name แนะนำเราว่าคุณอาจจะสนใจหนึ่งในโครงการไทยออแพร์ และแจ้งให้เราส่งอีเมลล์ให้กับคุณนะคะ\n\nคุณสามารถค้นหารายละเอียด หรือข้อมูลเพิ่มเติมของโครงการต่างๆ ได้ที่\n\nhttp://www.thaiaupair.com\n\nทีมงานหวังเป็นอย่างยิ่งที่จะได้ตอบข้อสักถามเพิ่มเติม และได้นำเสนอโอกาสในการได้เรียนรู้การใช้ชีวิตในต่างแดนให้แก่คุณนะคะ ขอบคุณค่ะ";

$subject="Thaiaupair.com-You've been referred to us by $name.";
mail($friendsemail, $subject, $autoreply);

$formcontent = "Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Friend's Name: $friendsname \n Friend's Email: $friendsemail \n Friend's Phone: $friendsphone";
$recipient = "info@thaiaupair.com";
$subject = "Refer A Friend";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent) or die("Error!"); 

echo '<img src="http://thaiaupair.com/Image/logophp.png" padding-bottom:10px>';
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Thank you for referring your friend to us!" . " -" . "<a href='Tell-A-Friend.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#df2590;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

The OUPUT I get in my email is not Thai, like this:

```
Name: à¸—à¸— 
Email: à¸—à¸— 
Phone: à¸—à¸— 
Friend's Name: à¸—à¸— 
Friend's Email: à¸—à¸— 
Friend's Phone: à¸—à¸—
```

I checked my encoding setting for all the parts I know (I don't know a lot right now, to be honest), like all the Page Properies are set to:

```
Document Type: XHTML 1.0 Transitional
Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
Unicode Normalization Form: C
```

I already us the meta tag:  as suggested in many websites I tried to learn from.

I now wonder if I should add something on my PHP code? 
Please help. I need to learn this the right way.

EDIT: I found out that the problem is not with my code at all. It's the Roundcube (email provider) settings. I only needed to change the encoding in Roundcube to utf-8 and it finally works!

Comment: Have you tried looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616201/sending-mail-with-php-in-forgein-languages? See if it would help

Comment: Thank you so much, Choz. I did look at the question and then I found out something. My PHP works great and shows the output perfectly in Thai in my personal Gmail, just not in Roundcube (info@thaiaupair.com). But what Amit mentioned about his solution, I just do not really understand how to fix my situation. I'll need to do some more research then. Could you please suggest as well?

Comment: If you send a Thai email from your personal Gmail account to the one in Roundcube, does that work? (just trying to rule out Roundcube). Have you tried adding the fourth parameter to the mail() function as suggested in that other thread (to add `charset=UTF-8`)

Comment: Thanks Gant, the company has been using this Roundcube for years and it shows the output in Thai fine. The older website seemed to use tis-620 though. I used Dreamweaver to make the new website and everything is automatically set to utf-8. I tried to follow the solution noted in the thread, now the Thai font shows as ????? instead..

Comment: I finally got it to work! I need to get to the settings in Roundcube and set the encoding to utf-8, simple as that!! Gosh.. Thank you guys so much for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use headers in e-mail

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $autoreply, $headers);
```

Comment: Did you check the answer??

Comment: Thank you so much, Abdulla. I finally found out that I needed to change the encoding setting in Roundcube to be utf-8. Now everything works fine. Should I come across any new issues related to encoding again somehow, I'll definitely try your suggestion. Thank you so, so very much :)

Comment: if my answer helpful up vote or accept it. Its help full for other users